# Congratulations, Raffzahn, on reaching 100k reputation!

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

Yesterday, [Raffzahn](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/6659/raffzahn) became the first user to reach 100 000 rep, earned from 10 questions and 893 answers.

[image: Raffzahn]

Some statistics:

- Over 1 in 4 questions have an answer by Raffzahn.
- Over 1 in 3 meta questions have an answer by Raffzahn.
- He has one of every awarded type of tag badge, except [[ • Amiga]](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/111/amiga)

  - … and [the only two](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=silver) silver tag badges.
- He's "reached" over 2.2 million people.

Congratulations, and thank you!

Comment: This is really an achievement.  Congratulations.

Comment: Wait. He had *a question* as well? Wonders of the universe… ;)

Answer (score 14):

Raffzahn is a machine. Long, detailed, annotated answers from a broad background. A great asset to the site.

Grats Raffzahn!

Answer (score 8):

I continue to be amazed, both by this site, and this particular user. For people interested in retrocomputers, both is a trove of reliable, fun and interesting information and trivia.

I'm not very active, but I really do enjoy reading yours - and others - answers on this site :) Thanks!